# How do I read a csv file and change the needed folders' directory

Tags: python, pandas, csv, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

I have a dataset which contains ~148,000 video folders each converted to frames of about avg of 30 frames.

I have 2 csv files for training and validation. I have been able to create an annotation file to label the data I require through the following code.

```ipython
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import os

Dir = "./DataSet/20bn-jester-v1/"

classes = ['No gesture', 'Thumb Down', 'Thumb Up','Swiping Down', 'Swiping Up', 'Swiping Left', 'Swiping Right' ]

class_dict = {k: v for v, k in enumerate(classes)}

#Will count frames in each example

def count_frame(folder_name):
    return len([frame for frame in os.listdir(Dir+str(folder_name)) if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(Dir+str(folder_name), frame))])

#reading training csv

df = pd.read_csv('DataSet/jester-v1-train.csv',sep=';',header=None)

# Getting the data for only selected classes
df = df[df[1].isin(classes)]

# Convert class labels into int value(Encoding)
df[3] = df[1].map(class_dict).astype(str)

# Apply the Count frame function and store the data in column 2
df[2] = df[0].apply(count_frame).astype(int)

# Re arrange the columns
# Where column 0 is folder name, column 1 is start frame, column 2 is end frame and column 3 is label
df = df[[0, 1, 2, 3]]

# setting column 1 values equal to 1
df[1] = 1

df
```

Which give me the following results.

[image]

I do the same for validation. I am just stumped on how to use the following information and use it to seperate the following files in column 0 into a seperate folder as I want to upload it to google drive but due to the sheer number of files and my internet being potato, I can not upload the whole dataset to the drive

EDIT: I have tar zip the file to try and upload it to google drive. Is there a way to unzip specific files with the files names in a text file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright so I managed to use the column 0 and savinig it as a csv file and the following code was used to copy from one directory to another

```ipyth
import pandas as pd
from shutil import copyfile
import os, shutil


src_directory = "test1/"
dest_directory = "test2/"

df = pd.read_csv('list.csv',sep=';',header= None)
for fileName in df[0]:
    src_file = src_directory + str(fileName)
    dest_file = dest_directory + str(fileName)
    shutil.copytree(src_file, dest_file)
```